Unable to Retrieve Multiple Secrets from Azure Key Vault in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I'm facing an issue with my Azure DevOps pipeline where I can successfully retrieve one secret from Azure Key Vault, but not the others. Specifically, I'm able to retrieve one secret, but when I try to retrieve other secrets, they are not being set correctly in the pipeline.
My Setup

Azure Key Vault Configuration:

I have multiple secrets stored in Azure Key Vault (my-keyvault).
The secrets include:

SecretOne
SecretTwo
SecretThree
SecretFour




Access Policies:

The service principal used by Azure DevOps has Get and List permissions for secrets.


Azure DevOps Pipeline Configuration:

The pipeline is configured to retrieve secrets using the AzureKeyVault@1 task.
I verified that the service principal has the correct access permissions.



Pipeline Script
Here is the simplified version of my pipeline script for testing secret retrieval:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my-azure-subscription'
    KeyVaultName: 'my-keyvault'
    SecretsFilter: 'SecretOne,SecretTwo,SecretThree,SecretFour'
    RunAsPreJob: true

- script: |
    echo "SecretOne: ${SecretOne}"
    echo "SecretTwo: ${SecretTwo}"
    echo "SecretThree: ${SecretThree}"
    echo "SecretFour: ${SecretFour}"
  displayName: 'Print Secrets for Verification'

Issue

The secret SecretOne is correctly retrieved and printed.
The other secrets (SecretTwo, SecretThree, and SecretFour) are not being retrieved and printed.

Debugging Steps Taken

Verified Access Policies:

Confirmed that the service principal has Get and List permissions in the Key Vault.


Checked Secret Names:

Ensured that the secret names are correctly specified and match exactly, including case sensitivity.


Tested with Azure CLI:

Verified that all secrets can be retrieved using Azure CLI commands.



Request for Help
I need assistance in understanding why only one secret is being retrieved successfully while the others are not. Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong and how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!


I'd suggest you use AzureKeyVault@2 instead of AzureKeyVault@1

Can you run the pipeline in Diagnostics mode (checkbox in the bottom left corner when you queue a new build) and paste the logs here?

What happens if you use round brackets $(SecretXXX) instead of curly brackets ${SecretXXX}?

which part of the logs would you like me to share? I do not want to expose any of my company's details. Will try the round brackets.

I used round brackets and tried to access two secrets and only secret1 is returning, not secret2 value. I also am using now KeyVault@2.

There must be something in the logs saying if the secrets were found or not, and if the corresponding pipeline variables were set. You're trying to use the secrets in the same jib, right?

@RuiJarimba yes, I am using the secrets in the same job. What I am seeing is the first variable shows output but the rest shows ***. I am reading online that that could just mean that it is masked.

Yes, if you're seeing ***, then the secret was retrieved successfully. It is being masked to avoid putting sensitive information in the pipeline logs.

Azure Pipelines makes an effort to mask secrets when emitting data to pipeline logs, so you may see additional variables and data masked in output and logs that are not set as secrets.
This is by design, as you don't want sensitive information being exposed in the logs.
Example:
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'repo-kv-demo'
    KeyVaultName: 'kv-demo-repo'
    SecretsFilter: 'secretDemo'
    RunAsPreJob: true

# other tasks here

- bash: |
    echo "Secret Found! $MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"        
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(secretDemo)

The output from the bash command should look like this:
Secret Found! ***


==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo "Secret Found! $MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/8beed5-4d1f-4aba-a1ab-9ade27ab0e.sh
Secret Found! ***

I tried with Secret2 and it says found.
